# Arduino + Dual H Bridge Motor Driver

Tags: ros, arduino, rosseral-arduino, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI all, I have an Arduino UNO and a dual H bridge MOSFET motor driver. I want to control two motors using this controller and Arduino via ROS(Fuerte/Groovy/Hydro). I can write a sketch to arduino just for run motors (digitalwrite & analogWrite). But I want to know how to communicate Arduino & ROS. Can I use ROSARIA instead of rosserial_arduino? If yes, please give me a clue to write an Arduino sketch.

Motor Driver from ebay,
(3-36V-10A-Peak-30A-Dual-Motor-Driver-Module-board-H-bridge-DC-MOSFET-IRF3205)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113666/arduino-+-dual-h-bridge-motor-driver/) by [Hasitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/8076/hasitha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2013-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROSARIA is specific to Pioneer and other robots from MobileRobots/ActivMedia and the communications protocol is in many ways Pioneer-specific. If you want to use a similar design (robot controller on Arduino communicating with ROS nodes on a PC) it might be easier to use your own, smaller protocol.

Other people who know more about Arduino can give some advice about that, but if you search this site you may find people doing similar projects, or you may find existing code on wiki.ros.org that could serve as an example.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2013-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

for example - my ORCP protocol for [4WD robot](https://github.com/RoboCraft/robot_4wd)

---

Originally posted by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) with karma: 471 on 2013-12-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1